# in this code how can i print car is red colour.. this qtion is belong to oops concept

Tags: java

package oops;

class vehicle{
int wheels;

```
vehicle( int noOfwheels){
    wheels = noOfwheels;
}
```

}
public class MyConstructor {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    vehicle car = new vehicle(4);
    vehicle scooty = new vehicle(2);
    
    System.out.println(scooty.wheels +  " wheels ");

}
```

}

Comment: Hi! Please, add more information about your problem into your question. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and *ask a question*. If English is not your first language, you may want to try a different forum. I find it very difficult to understand your question title.

Answer (score 2):

```
enum Color {    
  Red, Green, Blue;    
}

class Vehicle { 
  String name;
  int wheels;
  Color color;

  Vehicle(String name, Color color, int noOfwheels){
    this.name = name;
    this.wheels = noOfwheels;
    this.color = color;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s vehicle, %s color, %d wheels", this.name, this.color, this.wheels);
  }
    
} 

 public class MyConstructor {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Vehicle car = new Vehicle("car", Color.red, 4);
    Vehicle scooty = new Vehicle("scooty", Color.green, 2);
    
    System.out.println(scooty.toString());
    System.out.println(car.toString());

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it using two different ways:

##### Using enumerations

```java
public enum Color {
  BLACK, WHITE, RED, YELLOW, BLUE, MAGENTA /* I never seen magenta cars, but still, ahaha */
}
public class Vehicle {
  private String name;
  private Color color;
  private int wheels;

  public Vehicle(String name, Color color, int wheels) {
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.wheels = wheels;
  }
  // Getters, setters, toString(), ...
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vehicle car = new Vehicle("Toyota RAV4", Color.WHITE, 4);
  }
}
```

##### Using common strings

```java
public class Vehicle {
  private String name;
  private String color;
  private int wheels;

  public Vehicle(String name, Color color, int wheels) {
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.wheels = wheels;
  }
  // Getters, setters, toString(), ...
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vehicle car = new Vehicle("Toyota RAV4", "white", 4);
  }
}
```

##### Difference

When you use enumerations, there're only few colors that can be used, you can't pass a color that does not exist in `Color` enumeration, but it will protect your code from passing not a color values, like `new Vehicle("Toyota RAV4", "Potato", 4);`. Of course, potato is not a color and you should make a validation for it.